# Laravel wrap any existing query with or condition

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have an existing laravel model, with many where conditions chained to it.
*i.e WHERE username='john' AND (updated_at > "2017-01-01" OR ... ) AND ...*

I don't know how many previous queries there are, and i don't have access to them. I only have access to the model instance after it has received some where conditions.

i.e i have a function that receives a model as its parameter, and i want
to add an OR condition to already existing *wheres*

```
function notDeleted($model) {
  //  model has already a bunch of where/or where conditions at this point
  //  i want return rows, that match either all the previous conditions
  //  OR this new condition that i add inside this function.
}
```

I would like to add an OR condition, in the following way.

```
Select * from users WHERE ( (query1 AND query2 AND ...) OR deleted_at IS NULL);
```

if u simply use 
*->orWhere*, then the query will be

```
select * from users where query1 AND query2 AND ... OR deleted_at is null
```

Note: the table names, columns etc are made up for SO post, my actual use case is a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and this is how I solved it:

```
// Create new \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder with current wheres in a group
$new_query = $query_builder->getQuery()->forNestedWhere();
$new_query->addNestedWhereQuery($query_builder->getQuery());

// Add the new query in another group
$new_query->whereIn($fk_field,                                   
        function($q) use ($index_name, $args) {
            // Ignore the Sphinx stuff, just add your new condition here.
            $q->select(\DB::raw(SphinxSearch::getRawSelect($index_name)))
                ->where('query', SphinxSearch::getRawQueryString($args));
});

// Replace original \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder's internal              
// \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder with the new one                   
$query_builder->setQuery($new_query);
```

Comment: It clears all existing joins :( but good idea

Answer (score 0):

Put the criteria you want to wrap in a closure:

```php
$model->where(function($query) {
        $query->where('field', 'value')
              ->where('field2', 'value');
    })
    ->orWhereNull('deleted_at');
```

Comment: The catch is, that the criteria i want to wrap, has already been added to the model. Im looking for a way to wrap already existing/applied where conditions.

if you look at my post, it has a function "notDeleted". I'd like to add a single orWhere condition, to whatever conditions the parameter model already has.

Comment: You would need to first wrap the previous conditions into a closure.  If you don't have access to these, you may need to create another query with your 'OR' criteria and join the two in a Union.  https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#unions

Answer (score -1):

Try to wrap where condition like this below

```
SomeModel::where(function($q){
    $q->where(query1 AND query2 AND ...)
      ->orWhere(deleted_at IS NULL);
})->get();
```

Above code is just a sample. You need to modify to your requirements.

For more information check this link [Nested Parameter Grouping](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses)

Comment: posted a comment above that applies to this post too